# Scrapy uses scrapyredis distributed

Tags: scrapy

When I use scrapy to write a distributed crawler with scrapy-redis, I only store the request request queue in redis, and there is no storage deduplication fingerprint queue

```
# Spider code

import scrapy
from datetime import datetime
from machinedigikey.items import Detail_Item
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
class DgkUpdateDetailSpider(RedisSpider):

# setting
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter"
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.queue.PriorityQueue"
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True
REDIS_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300
}
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
```

```
# Startup method
scrapy crawl dgk_update_detail
```

No errors, but I checked that there is no heavy fingerprint in redis only dgk_update_detail:requests

Also ask if the code breaks during the running of the code, but does not clear the data in redis delete all the crawler code, modify and redeploy, will the entire crawler continue to crawl?

Stop the crawling method as:

```
Kill -s 9 id
```

Comment: The problem is solved because yield scrapy.Request Added time dont_filter=False Result caused by parameters